# Return to original buffer after opening REPL

Tags: org-mode, slime

I've got this in my `config.org` , which is called by my `init.el`:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun bauf/execute-startup-block ()
    (interactive)
    (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "startup")
       (org-babel-execute-src-block)))
#+end_src
```

then in an org-mode file I have this at the bottom:

```
...

* Comments

#+name: startup
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
;(progn (slime) (org-babel-execute-buffer))
(slime)
(org-babel-execute-buffer)
#+END_SRC

# Local Variables:
# eval: (bauf/execute-startup-block)
# End:
```

What I want is that when I open this file, it should automatically start a `slime` repl, then run all the code blocks in the org-mode file. The code above will start the slime repl just fine, but then it's not doing the `(org-babel-execute-buffer)`. I can then manually run `C-c C-v b` and it indeed runs all the code blocks. So, I'm guessing that after the `(slime)` is performed, it doesn't return focus to my calling org-mode buffer and the `(org-babel-execute-buffer)` is running to no avail in the slime repl buffer? If this is true, how do I tell it to return to the org-mode file and there run `(org-babel-execute-buffer)`?

Comment: `(save-current-buffer (slime))` ?

Comment: `(save-current-buffer (slime))` doesn't work. As I'm saying, once `(slime)` is called, it stays in that slime REPL buffer and doesn't return to do the `(org-babel-execute-buffer)`. I need it to return from the `(slime)` call.